# how to get the '0' entry in object

Tags: php

I have the following object:

```
stdClass Object ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [img_id] => 56 [img_name] => 5c9eeb51930ebe222ab26895dab7c348.png ) )
```

It is being dumped into a variable called $image_names. I am trying to get the entry for [0].

I have tried:

$image_names->0 but I get the error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER

I even tried $image_names[0]. I realize this should not work, but I thought I would give it a try. This does not return an error. But, it also does not return the data.

In this object structure, how do I get the object associated with the key [0]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same as always.

```
$image_names->{'0'}
```

Comment: Thanks. That was it. I've never had to access an object like this, so I don't have a 'Same as always'. Do you happen to know why the '0' has to be in curly brackets like that?

Comment: Because you're using a string for the attribute.

Comment: 0 is a string? I realize it can be, but here it appears to be a number. BTW, I am not questioning you, obviously you know, since your solution worked, but I am just wondering why you cannot use $var->0.

Comment: `0` is a number. `'0'` is a string. You cannot use literals to access attributes directly.

Comment: I think I understand. Are you saying in the object I posted, the '0' is not actually a number but rather some other data type?

Comment: Correct. It is a string.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the lesson Ignacio.